# JavaScript format current time and twenty minutes later

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to get current time and the time for twenty minutes later in certain format using JavaScript. The desired output should be in this format:

```
30/09/2017 22:11:23
dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss
```

Here is my code:

```
 //...
```

The output I have obtained:

```
30/09/2017 22:1506781883422:23
30/09/2017 22:11:23
```

The twenty minutes later one seemed wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var now = new Date();
var in20 = new Date(now.getTime() + (1000*60*20));// add 20 minutes

console.log(now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString());
console.log(in20.toLocaleDateString() + " " + in20.toLocaleTimeString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier and faster way:

```js
let currentTime = new Date;
let twentyMinutesLater = new Date;
twentyMinutesLater.setMinutes(twentyMinutesLater.getMinutes()+20);
console.log(currentTime.toString())
console.log(twentyMinutesLater.toString())
```

If you need to format the string, use the different toString() functions, provided by the Date class.